# UITextField to change API URL in Swift 5

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift5

I am new iOS Developer

I want to change the websiteLogo API with a textfield to change the URL.

how can I change the line with the ***
with a var and a textfield in my viewcontroller?

With screenshoot it's will be easier to understand what I want? Thank you !!! Guys. OneDriveLink. 1drv.ms/u/s!AsBvdkER6lq7klAqQMW9jOWQkzfl?e=fyqOeN

```
private init() {}
**private static var pictureUrl = URL(string: "https://logo.clearbit.com/:http://www.rds.ca")!**

private var task: URLSessionDataTask?

func getQuote(callback: @escaping (Bool, imageLogo?) -> Void) {

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        task?.cancel()

    task = session.dataTask(with: QuoteService.pictureUrl) { (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                callback(false, nil)
                return
                }

                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                callback(false, nil)
                return
                }

                let quote = imageLogo(image: data)
                    callback(true, quote)
                    print(data)
                }
        }
    task?.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Please share what the error message is.

Comment: It's in my .swift this code. but I have textfield in my viewcontroller. How can I change my textfield content and change the  private pictureUrl var in this code above... Thank you!

Comment: are you familiar with setters?

Comment: no I will try my own to understand more ( I always know my value of my var so. I'm not an expect to Init. and play with class.. I know the answer is around here but I have work to do to understand very clear this setters! Thank You. If you want to help me. let me know!

Comment: You can connect your `textField` to your code using an `IBAction`, see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Comment: Thank you to take time to answer. I know how to do that. I want to know. How I got my var with the answer of the textfield input. I want to place this value string to my code above replacing a URL with the new URL that I write in the textfield. I don't know if you understand?

Comment: Where is that code located, in your `ViewController`? Take the `pictureURL` property out of the method so that it is accessible to your `IBAction` And then you can change it.

Comment: With screenshoot it's will be, easier to understand what I want? Thank you !!! Guys. OneDriveLink. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsBvdkER6lq7klAqQMW9jOWQkzfl?e=fyqOeN

Comment: Please don't use screenshots on SO. Both answers below are correct, you need to pass your URL string to the `getQuote()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please **don't use screenshots do show your code.** If you want help, others typically copy/paste your code to check whats wrong with it.

There are some minor issues with your code. Some hints from me:

1. Start your types with a big letter, like `ImageLogo` not `imageLogo`:
2. Avoid statics
3. Avoid singletons (they are almost statics)
4. Hand in the `pictureUrl` into `getQuote`

```
struct ImageLogo {
    var image:Data
}

class QuoteService {
    private var task: URLSessionDataTask?

    func getQuote(from pictureUrl:URL, callback: @escaping (Bool, ImageLogo?) -> Void) {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        task?.cancel()

        task = session.dataTask(with: pictureUrl) { 
            (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    callback(false, nil)
                    return
                }

                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                    callback(false, nil)
                    return
                }

                let quote = ImageLogo(image: data)
                callback(true, quote)
                print(data)
              }
        }
        task?.resume()
    }
}
```

5. Store an instance of `QuoteService` in your view controller
6. Call `getQuote` on that instance, handing in the `pictureUrl`

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    var quoteService:QuoteService!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.quoteService = QuoteService()
    }

    func toggleActivityIndicator(shown:Bool) { /* ... */ }
    func update(quote:ImageLogo) { /* ... */ }
    func presentAlert() { /* ... */ }

    func updateconcept() {
          guard let url = URL(string:textField.text!) else {
              print ("invalid url")
              return
          }
          toggleActivityIndicator(shown:true)
          quoteService.getQuote(from:url) {
              (success, quote) in
              self.toggleActivityIndicator(shown:false)
              if success, let quote = quote {
                    self.update(quote:quote)
              } else {
                  self.presentAlert()
              }
          }
    }

    /* ... */

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to pass `textfield` Text(`URL` Enter By user) in Web Services

Add a parameter `url_str` in `getQuote` function definition first and pass `textfield` value on that parameters

```
fun getQuote(url_str :  String, callback : @escaping(Bool, ImgaeLogo/)->void){

}
```